# How do I add grain to an image using the ImageJ API

Tags: api, imagej

I am new to ImageJ and I am seeking to **add grain** (as defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_grain) to an image using the programmatic API of ImageJ.

- Is it possible? If so how?
- Where is the relevant documentation/Javadocs regarding adding grain
  to an image using ImageJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start in `Process > Noise`, described in [*ImageJ User Guide: §29.6 Noise*](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-29.html#toc-Subsection-29.6). You'll have to decide if the existing implementations can be made to meet your requirements.

> *Where I can find documentation on how to achieve this using the actual API instead of the UI*.

As discussed in [*ImageJ Macro Language*](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html), one easy way is to start `Plugin > Macros > Record` and then operate the desired GUI command. This reveals the macro command name and any settings, for example:

```
run("Add Noise");
run("Add Specified Noise...", "standard=16");
```

You can apply such a macro to multiple files using the `-batch` command line option.

If you want to use a feature directly from Java, see [*ImageJ programming tutorials*](http://albert.rierol.net/imagej_programming_tutorials.html).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where I can find documentation on how to achieve this using the actual API instead of the UI?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; I've suggested two paths above.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that there was no language tag so I choose to write an example in Scala. The code below would read twice the lena.png image, and create two ImagePlus objects and add noise to one of them.

I am kind of guessing that the API comment is related to the software library ImageJ instead of the graphical user interface/program ImageJ.

An ImagePlus has a processor (of type ij.process.ImageProcessor) that you can get a reference to with the method getProcessor()

(getProcessor() is a method here that acts on the object lenaWithNoise and returns a reference to the current ImageProcessor (attached to lenaWithNose)).

The method noise acts on the image that the ImageProcessor handles, and has no return value (void method or in scala unit)

```
import ij._

object Noise {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val lenaNoiseFree:ImagePlus = IJ.openImage("src/test/scala/images/lena.png")
    val lenaWithNoise:ImagePlus = IJ.openImage("src/test/scala/images/lena.png")
    lenaNoiseFree.show()
    lenaWithNoise.getProcessor().noise(10.0)
    lenaWithNoise.show()
 }
}
```